# boxruled formatted algorithm text overflowing

Tags: algorithm2e

I have a algorithm which is really a sequence of long statements and I'd like it to be inside a box but the following gets the word wrapping wrong.  Anyone knows why?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\RestyleAlgo{boxruled}
\begin{algorithm}
\scriptsize    
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a long text that overflow the box jjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjj j jjjjjjjj j j jjjjjjjj jjjjj j jj jjjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj j jjjj jjjj jjjj j j  jjjjjjj jjj jjjjj jjjjjjjj jj jjjj jjj j jjjjjjj
\item This is a long text that overflow the box jjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjj j jjjjjjjj j j jjjjjjjj jjjjj j jj jjjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj j jjjj jjjj jjjj j j  jjjjjjj jjj jjjjj jjjjjjjj jj jjjj jjj j jjjjjjjj
\item This is a long text that overflow the box jjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjj j jjjjjjjj j j jjjjjjjj jjjjj j jj jjjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj j jjjj jjjj jjjj j j  jjjjjjj jjj jjjjj jjjjjjjj jj jjjj jjj j jjjjjjj
\end{enumerate}
\caption{A caption}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I've tried putting it in `miniboxes` and `\vbox` but nothing works

Answer (score 1):

REVISED.  The line `\addtolength\linewidth{-4ex}` needs to be added inside the `algorithm` environment.  At first, I thought the adjustment was a multiple of `\leftmargini` and/or `\labelsep`, but further testing in this MWE proves that belief to be false.  Rather, a fixed adjustment to the `\linewidth` seems to work out best.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

This is a long text that overflow the box jjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjj j jjjjjjjj j j jjjjjjjj jjjjj j jj jjjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj j jjjj jjjj jjjj j j  jjjjjjj jjj jjjjj jjjjjjjj jj jjjj jjj j jjjjjjj

\RestyleAlgo{boxruled}
\begin{algorithm}
\addtolength\linewidth{-4ex}
\scriptsize    
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a long text that overflow the box jjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjj j jjjjjjjj j j jjjjjjjj jjjjj j jj jjjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj j jjjj jjjj jjjj j j  jjjjjjj jjj jjjjj jjjjjjjj jj jjjj jjj j jjjjjjj
\item This is a long text that overflow the box jjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjj j jjjjjjjj j j jjjjjjjj jjjjj j jj jjjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj j jjjj jjjj jjjj j j  jjjjjjj jjj jjjjj jjjjjjjj jj jjjj jjj j jjjjjjjj
\item This is a long text that overflow the box jjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjj j jjjjjjjj j j jjjjjjjj jjjjj j jj jjjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj j jjjj jjjj jjjj j j  jjjjjjj jjj jjjjj jjjjjjjj jj jjjj jjj j jjjjjjj
\end{enumerate}
\caption{A caption}
\end{algorithm}

\leftmargini=3\leftmargini
\labelsep=6\labelsep
\begin{algorithm}
\addtolength\linewidth{-4ex}
\scriptsize    
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a long text that overflow the box jjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjj j jjjjjjjj j j jjjjjjjj jjjjj j jj jjjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj j jjjj jjjj jjjj j j  jjjjjjj jjj jjjjj jjjjjjjj jj jjjj jjj j jjjjjjj
\item This is a long text that overflow the box jjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjj j jjjjjjjj j j jjjjjjjj jjjjj j jj jjjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj j jjjj jjjj jjjj j j  jjjjjjj jjj jjjjj jjjjjjjj jj jjjj jjj j jjjjjjjj
\item This is a long text that overflow the box jjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjj jjjj jjjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjj j jjjjjjjj j j jjjjjjjj jjjjj j jj jjjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjj jjjj jjjjjjj jjjjjjjj j jjjj jjjj jjjj j j  jjjjjjj jjj jjjjj jjjjjjjj jj jjjj jjj j jjjjjjj
\end{enumerate}
\caption{A caption}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]